# Antlr4cs: Same grammar different results vs Java tools

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have followed the instructions here: https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/wiki and here: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4

I have morphed my grammar from the opening example but it works with the Java tools (antlr4.bat and grun.bat) but not with my console app as configured by the sharwell wiki.

Java (inside a folder with only the Hello.g4 file):

```
antlr4 Hello.g4
javac *.java
grun Hello prog -gui

I then type "hello world" then Return then "^Z" then Return
The gui pops up an matches my grammar correctly
```

C# (only difference is the @parser and @lexer directives are not used in the Java version)

Hello.g4:

```
grammar MetaMeta;

@parser::members
{
protected const int EOF = Eof;
}

@lexer::members
{
protected const int EOF = Eof;
protected const int HIDDEN = Hidden;
}

prog    :   stmt NL* EOF;

stmt    :   hello eos;

hello   :   HELLO ID;

eos     :   ';' | NL;

HELLO   :   'hello';
ID      :   [a-z]+;
NL      :   '\r'? '\n';
WS      :   [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

Program.cs:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        (new Program()).Run();
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        var text = "hello world\n";
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("START");
            RunParser(text);
            Console.Write("DONE. Hit RETURN to exit: ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex);
            Console.Write("Hit RETURN to exit: ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private void RunParser(string text)
    {
        var input = new AntlrInputStream(text);
        var lexer = new MetaMetaLexer(input);
        var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new MetaMetaParser(tokens);
        var context = parser.prog();
        var visitor = new MyVisitor();
        visitor.VisitProg(context);
    }
```

When running the program I get the following:

```
START
HelloVisitor VisitProg
 Visit Symbol=<EOF>
DONE. Hit RETURN to exit:
```

My visitor is the same as the code example on the cs wiki.  Thanks for any help.  ;)
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would have included your visitor code here, you would have received an answer much faster.

The visitor you are using does not override `AbstractParseTreeVisitor<Result>.VisitTerminal(ITerminalNode)`. Therefore, the default implementation of this method is used each time a terminal node is reached, which simply returns `DefaultResult()` (which by default is just `default(Result)`).

Comment: I did mention that it was the same as the wiki.  I will add it below for completeness.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The modified visitor code is as follows:

```
public class MyVisitor : AbstractParseTreeVisitor<object>
{
    public override object VisitTerminal(ITerminalNode node)
    {
        var text = node.Symbol.Text;
        if (text == "\n")
            text = @"\n";
        Console.WriteLine(" Visit Symbol={0}", text);
        return base.VisitTerminal(node);
    }
}
```

And the modified calling code is as follows:

```
    private void RunParser(string text)
    {
        var input = new AntlrInputStream(text);
        var lexer = new MetaMetaLexer(input);
        var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new MetaMetaParser(tokens);
        var context = parser.prog();
        var visitor = new MyVisitor();
        visitor.Visit(context); //changed to just Visit
    }
```

I added this for completeness, but awarded the correct answer to Sam above.

Thanks, 
Scott